# How to specify which editor is used when editing posts with WP-CLI?

Tags: wp-cli

On macOS, when I do `wp @alias post edit 1` I get `nano`. The same happens when I do `EDITOR=emacs wp @alias post edit 1`. I want `emacs`, My `EDITOR` is set to `emacs`. How do I get `emacs`?

Note that `env|grep nano` doesn't return anything. And most of the time the `EDITOR` var seems to work just fine.

I found this in the [documentation](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/config/):

> To set an environment variable on demand, simply place the environment variable definition before the WP-CLI command you mean to run.

```
# Use vim to edit a post
$ EDITOR=vim wp post edit 1
```

> To set the same environment variable value for every shell session, you’ll need to include the environment variable definition in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc file

```
# Always use vim to edit a post
export EDITOR=vim
```

So this looks like a bug to me. And someone else was having a [very similar issue](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/4809), but it wasn't deemed to be a bug, and I haven't found a solution so far.

When I run `wp post edit 1` on my server it works fine. I'm guessing the problem is related to `getenv` and using wp-cli remotely. I tried settings `EDITOR=emacs` in various places ([through this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/389203/185616)), but no luck so far.

Even after adding a symlink from `nano` to `emacs` inside `/usr/local/bin`, `wp-cli` still insists on opening `/usr/bin/nano` despite my `PATH` preference for `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Does that happen without an `@alias` as well?

Answer (score 0):

I thought the command must be typed like so:

```
$ export EDITOR=emacs; wp post edit 1
```

Which is exactly how it's working for me on my 10.14.5 macOS right now. And on Linux as well.

---

Maybe something is misconfigured on your Mac. Or `@alias` is interfering. Can you try to rerun that command without `@alias` or on a fresh macOS installation?

Comment: No it must not. It can be typed like this, but it's slightly different.
And no, unfortunately this doesn't give me the desired result either.

Comment: Yeah it's a good idea to run `wp` locally, I'm pursuing this now.
First have to set up mysql locally (again). Will update here with my findings.